# How to make a link type of a news automatically?

Tags: views, 7

I made a content type what called *news*, and I have created a **list(text)** field type to grab the type of news and name it **news_type** and it's value is **Sport, Health, Technology, Economic** and others.

I want each of this type comes to a block as a link to all of that type news. Something like below:

[image]

and How to make each news type a link?

Some people say you should use View, How to use view for this?
Please describe step by step.

Comment: you can do by adding that content-type inside view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a View named "xyz" & select content of type "news"
2. Select page or block
3. Add fields what you want to show or if you need filtration then you can filter your content.
4. & save.

Comment: Thanks, How to make each news type a link?