# How to use URL as a filter in view module?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I asked a question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150874/how-to-make-a-link-type-of-a-news-automatically) and now I am going to create a view that the view take the URL and use it as a filter.

[image: view filter]

and I want to have a the view by a **dynamic filter** use the URL path and show the result by different type something like sport, economy, etc.

Pathauto: **news/[node:news_type]/[node:title]**

I want to use [node:news_type] in my filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Contextual filter under the Advanced pane in your view's edit page.

1. Look for your field, it would probably be *Content: News type* then add the field
2. Under ***WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL*** select Provide default value
3. Choose Raw value from URL for **Type**
4. Choose 2 for **Path component**
5. Check **Use path alias**